# Using 'is' at the end of these specific sentences

Tags: grammar

> I don't know what the problem is.
>   I don't know which one correct is.

Some people told me the first sentence is correct and the second sentence is incorrect.
My question is:
Why using the word **'is'** (at the end of the sentense) can be correct in the **first** sentence, but not in the **second** sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Correct is an adjective, and problem is a noun.

The second sentence is understandable, but it's the way Yoda talks.

To be correctly idiomatic while putting "is" at the end, one would write the second sentence:

```
I don't know which the correct one is.
```

Note "one" is a noun here.

More common and idiomatically correct would be to write:

```
I don't know which one is correct.
```

Note with regard to your first sentence, the answer to the question might be "The problem is X." While you would not state "The correct is X." because "is" requires a subject noun not just an adjective. An answer to the second type of question could be "The correct **one** is X."

Comment: +1 (I would give you +2 for the 'Yoda" joke if I could.) I would add that there is a school of thought and English language training that states you do not end a sentence with "is". I doubt you would even be able to diagram any of these two sentences ending with that word. In writing, I would not end a sentence with "is", not even in an informal context (unless it is a direct quote). I may say a sentence with "is' at the end. However this would be for dramatic effect or I am reciting a direct quote. Otherwise, it is predominant in American usage and is widely accepted in various contexts.

Answer (score 1):

It has to deal with the way verb phrases change when you have a question, as opposed to a statement. Let's look at a few examples:

> *What is* the problem?

but

> I don't know *what* the problem *is*.

Another example:

> *Who are* these people?

but

> My mother wonders *who* these people *are*.

What these examples show is that in a sentence that's a statement (not a question), words like "who", "what" aren't directly followed by a verb like they are in a question.

So let's try to work backwards from your second example, and see what the corresponding question would look like.

- Statement: "I don't know which one correct is."
- Question: we move the verb after 'which', and we get "Which is one correct?". That's not a valid English sentence, so there was a problem with our statement too.

There are two ways to ask that question:

> Version 1: "Which is the correct one?"
>
> Explanation: we start with "which is", and that looks like our familiar pattern of question word followed by a verb. The corresponding statement then looks like "I don't know *which* the correct one *is*", after we move the verb 'is' to the end. That's a valid statement.

or

> Version 2: "Which one is correct?" (or "Which one is the correct one?")
>
> Explanation: the question word 'which' doesn't have a verb right after it. In that case, the word order in the corresponding statement doesn't change. We get "I don't know *which one is correct*."